# resizing images in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

i want to resize my images (orignal size is 1080p) but they dont resize properly and i dont know why. The Images just dont have the right size sometimes. On my emulator and my old 800*480 smartphone it works fine but on my nexus 4 with 1280*768 things dont look right. There is no problem reading the right screen resolution. There is just a bug with my resize procedure. Please help me.

```
private float smaller;
smaller = height/1080;   //height is screenheight; in my case its 768 because of landscape

object.bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,(int)(smaller*bitmap.getWidth()) ,(int)(smaller*bitmap.getHeight()), true);
```

In the end the height is not resized to 768/1080*bitmapheight and i dont know why.

edit:

these are screenshots of my programm showing the images have not the same height

First image:

imgur.com/STSgAOd,Wh3fVdX

Second:

imgur.com/STSgAOd,Wh3fVdX#1

As you can see the Images are not equal in terms of height. On my emulator and my old smartphone they look right. The Images should not touch the bottom but on my nexus 4 they do.

also tryed double:

```
private double factor;
factor = ((double)screenheight/(double)1080);
objekte.bitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,(int)(factor*bitmap.getWidth()) ,(int)(factor*bitmap.getHeight()), true);
```

same bad result

Answer (score 0):

You asume the height needs to resize the most(look at your height/1080). I might be that the width has to resize the most. I use this to scale them:

```
//Calculate what scale is needed
double xFactor = (double)image.Width/(double)ScreenWidth;
double yFactor = (double)image.Height/(double)ScreenHeight;
double factor = xFactor;
if(yFactor>xFactor){
    factor = yFactor;
}

int imageWidth = Convert.ToInt32(im.Width / factor);
int imageHeight = Convert.ToInt32(im.Height / factor);
```

Note: this is written in C#. It needs some changes to work.
Note2: this makes sure the image will be full screen.(as much as possible, because it is scalled)

Comment: Ok so basically you want me to use double instead of float right? I can only resize by height and not by width because of the structure my programm has.

Comment: Double or float, you can use what you want. "I can only resize by height and not by width because of the structure my programm has." Please explain the because it doesn't make realy sense to me.

Comment: Ok lets take flappy bird as example. The height of the bitmaps is really important because of the style of the game. If i would resize by width the obstacles would get bigger if the screen gets "longer".

Comment: I got it. My fault i wasn't clear enough. You calculate the the biggest factor and resize both with ad height, not only the witdh.

Comment: have you calculated the factor like me in my example?

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by integer division, you can see that with -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int height = 768;
    float smaller = (float) height / 1080; // <-- force float
    float test = height / 1080;            // <-- integer division, 
                                       // and assign the int result to the float.
    System.out.println("test: " + test);
    System.out.println("smaller: " + smaller);
}
```

Output is

```
test: 0.0
smaller: 0.7111111
```

Comment: hmm this seems not to be the problem either - wait let me add screenshots

Comment: First image: http://imgur.com/STSgAOd,Wh3fVdX      Second: http://imgur.com/STSgAOd,Wh3fVdX#1   As you can see the Images are not equal in terms of height On my emulator and my old smartphone look right. The Images should not touch the bottom but on my nexus they do.